# vagrant add an interface without setting an IP address

Tags: vagrant

I'm working through the [puppet openstack instructions](https://github.com/snowch/puppet-openstack), and one of the requirements is as follows:

- Each of the machines running the Openstack services should have a minimum of 2 NICS.

  - One for the public/internal network. This nic should be assigned an IP address
  - One of the virtual machine network. **This nic should not have an ipaddress assigned**

I've tried to specify a private network in Vagrant without an address, but hit the following error when calling `vagrant up`:

```
* An IP is required for a private network.
```

My first thought is to run a provision script to set the network, but there are warnings not to modify the network configuration files (the box is CentOS):

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth2
#VAGRANT-BEGIN
# The contents below are automatically generated by Vagrant. Do not modify.
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.55.5
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
DEVICE=eth2
PEERDNS=no
#VAGRANT-END
```

Any ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: could you show your Vagrantfile configuration?

Comment: @Rob3 - it's here: https://github.com/snowch/stratos-developer-tools/blob/cloudstack/Vagrantfile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end, I created an 'unmanaged' network card by adding a virtualbox internal network:

```
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nic2", "intnet"]
```

Comment: Vagrant will support unmanaged private networks in a future release: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3015

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: ""
```

Comment: This threw an error for me: ```/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:266:in `hostonly_config': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)```

Comment: No it does not. Next time show the version of vagrant and virtualbox you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
node.vm.network :private_network, "ip": '0.0.0.0', auto_network: true
```